# PHP String to Array Split

Tags: php, arrays, string

So I want to try something a little different.

Let's say someone puts in an input text box the following two examples.

"name:Justin"

I want to go into an array
Index| Col   Val

[0]    Name   Justin

In second Example
"name:Justin,state:CA"

[0]    Name   Justin
[1]    State   CA

Basically I have a page where Im using text inputs to query a remote database.  I was thinking of doing some conditionals so that they can specify which column to search.  Then pushing that to do multiple column searches but I need a way to read the results.  I figured out how to do it for 1 result but I'm drawing a blank on how to do it if they want to do multiple.

Thoughts?

Comment: `array_map(function($kv) {return explode(":",$kv);},explode(",",$input));` should get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `explode()` to generate an `array` and `array_map()` to replace `:` by `space`. Example:

```
$str = 'name:Justin,state:CA';
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$result = array_map(function($v){return str_replace(':', ' ', $v);},$arr);

print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```